# How to make flatpak applications use standard locations for user data files?

Tags: xdg, flatpak

Applications installed with Flatpak are keeping user data and configuration under `~/.var/app/` (see [Wiki](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem) and [documentation](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/conventions.html#xdg-base-directories)).

I would like the applications installed with Flatpak to reuse the configuration and data left from the system versions of the same applications.  That is, I want them to keep user data in `~/.local/share`, `~/.config`, `~/.cache`, instead of under `~/.var/app`.

At first I was hoping that configuring environment variables `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, `XDG_DATA_HOME`, `XDG_CACHE_HOME` [could suffice](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/conventions.html#xdg-base-directories), or that it [could be enough](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#filesystem-access) to start the application with `--filesystem` options:

```
 $ flatpak run --filesystem=xdg-config --filesystem=xdg-cache \
  --filesystem=xdg-data <application-id>
```

However, this did not seem to work.

What is the correct way to make Flatpak applications reuse user data and configurations in standard locations?

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do here? It's confusing.

Comment: Sorry,what is confusing?  I want the applications like Skype or Lollypop that I install with Flatpak keep their data in the same locations in the user home folder where they would normally do when installed on Ubuntu with `apt` from some PPA.  That way I would be able to easily replace a PPA version with Flatpak version and vice versa.

Comment: Are you trying to get all of a specific user's apps to maintain it's data in `~/.var/app` or do you want to share data across a given app to all users?

Comment: I do not want Flatpak apps to keep their data in `~/.var/app`, I want them to store it in `~/.local/share`, `~/.config`, `~/.cache`.

Comment: OK, so you want to override where Flatpak keeps its data.

Comment: As a workaround, why not just make symlinks out of that dir to where you want it?

Comment: Assuming you saw this page? - https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem.

Comment: It feels a bit like hacking the implementation instead of using an interface... I was hoping that there were some options I could set.

Comment: Let's call it plan B 8-)

Comment: What didn't work with the env variables? Those seem like the way to do this?

Comment: There's this thread from hell too - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1575053.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by specifying the directory after `--filesystem=xdg-config` and including mount parameters after that. I'm not sure if the mount parameters are necessary, but try putting this in this `finish-args` section of your application's manifest .json.

```
"finish-args": [
    "--filesystem=xdg-config/<config-dir>:create",
    "--filesystem=xdg-cache/<cache-dir>:create",
    "--filesystem=xdg-data/<data-dir>:create"
],
```